# Symfony Panther - Testing Stripe form

Tags: forms, symfony, testing, phpunit, stripe-payments

in my app I would like to test my Stripe form created with Stripe Elements. So I want to fill out the form with Panther ( https://github.com/symfony/panther ), but it seems totally impossible.

Here's an example of a Stripe form: https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/

For example, if I want to automatically fill in the field corresponding to the card number (in the 1st example, this is the input with the name 'cardnumber'), I tried two things:

```
$crawler->filter("input[name=cardnumber]")->sendKeys("4242 4242 4242 4242");
```

or

```
$this->client->getWebDriver()->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('cardnumber'))->sendKeys("4242 4242 4242 4242");
```

This returns me the following error :

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException : no such element:
> Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[name='cardnumber']"}

So I tried by running a javascript line :

```
$this->client->executeScript("$('input[name=cardnumber]').value = '4242 4242 4242 4242'");
```

It didn't bring anything.

As a result, I find myself completely blocked and I do not know how to overcome this problem

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ Panther but have you tried adding an interval that checks if the element exists and runs the line only if/when it does ? Stripe takes some time to load so that element probably doesn't exist at all when you run your line.

Comment: In fact the problem would come from the fact that stripe generates iframes for each field. I must therefore enter these frames to be able to enter the inputs. But it seems complicated because the iframes are coming from another host, and therefore, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Otherwise, yes, I waited for stripe to load correctly :)